Power Bi - Error when processing the Excel data in the dataset (while refreshing via semantic model)
I have a Power BI dashboard that uses Kusto and Excel as data sources. The Kusto data is imported, and all Excel files are stored in a SharePoint folder. To refresh the dashboard, I’ve scheduled a refresh in the semantic model of the report.
However, I’m encountering the following error during the scheduled refresh. It seems like there’s a connectivity issue, but I’m unsure what configuration is needed.
I’m able to refresh the dashboard manually by opening it in Power BI, refreshing it from the Home tab, and publishing it again.
Additionally, my dashboard is in the workspace ABC, while the SharePoint folder with the Excel files is in a different workspace (XYZ).
Error:
Data source error{"error":{"code":"Premium_ASWL_Error","pbi.error":`{"code":"Premium_ASWL_Error","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"Premium_ASWL_Error_Details_Label","detail":{"type":1,"value":"We are unable to refresh the semantic model because the model uses a data connection configured for Workspace Identity authentication, but the workspace has no identity, or the model owner does not have permissions to use the workspace identity. Please configure a workspace identity and make sure the model owner has Contributor (or higher) access to the workspace, or use a different authentication method."}}]}}} Table: Mapping Table.`


